# FileSystemException: Cannot open file, path

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to the read an excel that will be provided from the user via `file_picker: ^2.0.13` using `spreadsheet_decoder: ^1.2.0`, here's the methode of reading the file :

```
void _excelReader({String filepath}) async {
    var file = filepath;
    var bytes = File(file).readAsBytesSync();
    var decoder = SpreadsheetDecoder.decodeBytes(bytes, update: true);
    for (var table in decoder.tables.keys) {
      print(table);
      print(decoder.tables[table].maxCols);
      print(decoder.tables[table].maxRows);
      for (var row in decoder.tables[table].rows) {
        print('$row');
      }
    }
  }
```

I get this exception when trying to run :

```
FileSystemException: Cannot open file, path = '(/data/user/0/com.example.sms_sender_app/cache/file_picker/Classeur.xlsx)' (OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2)
```

I also tried to read the file via `excel: ^1.1.5` and the same exception was catched.

Comment: Did you add necessary permissions in the manifest file ?

Comment: This is what i added : <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

Comment: Are you sure that the file exists there when you are reading the content ? Can you try opening some other files from a different location ?

Comment: Actually even when I put some thing like C:/Users/xxx/Files.xlsx in the path, I mean from the local computer Storage, I get the same Exception catched.

Comment: Use the [device file explorer](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/device-file-explorer) and check whether your file exists. Also copy the excel file to Downloads or Documents folder of your Android device and try to read.

Comment: One more thing, If you are hard-coding the file-path, that can be an issue.

Comment: I'm confused because when reading the example writen under excel 1.1.5 plugin in pub.dev, it clearly shows that the path could be from the local computer Storage var file = "/Users/kawal/Desktop/form.xlsx".

Comment: Also, is the path_provider plugin could be necessary in my case ?

Comment: Probably the example is for Flutter web, I'm currently checking the Android one. Will update

Comment: Your code works perfectly with correct path. I've used path_provider to get the correct path and passed that to your function and it printed correct output. Seems like the issue is in your path.

Comment: Can you please show me how you did ?

Comment: So if I got this right, the process should be file_picker -> path_provider -> excel_plugin ?

Comment: If you are using file picker I don't think you need to use path_provider. You can get the file like this `FilePickerResult result = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles();

if(result != null) {
   File file = File(result.files.single.path);
} else {
   // User canceled the picker
}`

Comment: Really sorry for the delayed answer, thank you so much for your help that worked, you are a life saver :)

Comment: No worries. Happy Coding !!!